# Timing issue when reading data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a java class (CourseViewTeachers) where I am reading the name of a user from the firebase database using user's uid.I have written the code to read the data in the constructor of this class.
The constructor is given below.

```
public CourseViewTeachers(Courses courses)
{
    super(courses.getCourse_uid(), courses.getTecher_uid(), courses.getName());
    databaseReference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(getTecher_uid());
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User teacher = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            teacherName = teacher.getUser_name();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I am using this class to populate a custom array adapter. When I am creating a object of this class in a fragment and  returning the variable 'teacherName' , it is returning null.
 Code where I am populating the adapter is given below

```
courseListView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_courses_list);
courseListView.setAdapter(adapter);
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                courseList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    CourseViewTeachers courses = new CourseViewTeachers(snapshot.getValue(Courses.class));

                    if(courses.getTecher_uid().equals(fb_user.getUid()))
                    {
                        courseList.add(courses);

                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I have two questions:

- Why is this happening?
- How to resolve this issue?

Edit: To clarify where I am getting null
The adapter variable in the second code snippet is an object of a custom array adapter class. In the getView() function of the arrayAdapter calls getTeacherName() of CourseViewTeachers class.This function just returns the value of variable 'teacherName'. 
The code of the custom array adapter:

```
public class CourseViewTeachersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CourseViewTeachers> {

private Context context;
private List<CourseViewTeachers> list;

public CourseViewTeachersAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<CourseViewTeachers> list)
{
    super(context, 0 , list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
{
    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null)
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.course_view_teachers_layout,parent,false);

    CourseViewTeachers obj = list.get(position);

    TextView courseView = listItem.findViewById(R.id.course_teachers_view_course_name);
    courseView.setText(obj.getName());

    TextView teacherName = listItem.findViewById(R.id.course_teachers_view_teacher_name);
    teacherName.setText("Teacher : " + obj.getTeacherName());

    return listItem;
}
```

}

Comment: When you instantiate an instance of `CourseViewTeachers`, `teacherName` is not immediately available because it is set by an asynchronous callback `onDataChange`.  The callback will occur at some point later (on the "main" thread).

Comment: @Andy How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does `teacher.getUser_name()` return correct data? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes it returns correct data

Comment: Then where's the issue? In which place is the data null?

Comment: @AlexMamo The 'adapter' object (see in the second code snippet) which is a custom array adapter calls a function getTeacherName() (this function is defined in TeacherCourseView class). When getTeacherName() is called it returns null.

Comment: @AlexMamo getTeacherName() just returns the variable 'teacherName'

Comment: I cannot see anywhere in your a getTeacherName() methid that return null. Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.